# doctrine replace onetoone relation from inverse side

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have two entities `Product` and `Print` with one to one relation, where `Product` is a parent entity and `Print` is a child, but "owning side" is a `Print` (in database `print` table 'll have a `product_id` and foreign key)

Product:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class Product
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    public int $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     */
    public string $name;


    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
    public string $description;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     */
    public bool $available;


    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Print", mappedBy="product", cascade={"persist", "remove"},  orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    public Print $print;


    public function __construct(
        int $id,
        string $name,
        string $description,
        bool $available,
    ) {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->description = $description;
        $this-available = $available;
    }

    public function udpate(
        string $name,
        string $description,
        bool $available,
        Print $print,
    ) {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->description = $description;
        $this-available = $available;
        $this->replacePrint($$print);
    }


    public function replacePrint(Print $print): void
    {
        $this->print = $print;
    }

}
```

and Print:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class Print
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    public int $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    public array $key;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    public array $value;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Product", inversedBy="print")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     */
    public Product $product;

    public function __construct(Product $product, string $key, string $value)
    {
        $this->product = $blueprint;
        $this->key = $key;
        $this->value = value;
    }
}
```

when I'm inserting new product all is fine

```
$product = new Product($id, $name, $description, $available);
$product->replacePrint(new Print($product, $key, $value));

$em->persist($product);
$em->flush
```

it's inserting product and related print, generating new id for a print

But now when I want to update prodcut:

```
$product = $em->find(Product::class, $id);
$product->udpate($name, $description, $available);
$product->replacePrint(new Print($product, $key, $value));

$em->persist($product);
$em->flush
```

I'm getting error `Cannot assign null to property App\\Entity\\Print::$id of type int`

Comment: I tried to play with `orphanRemoval=true` adding it to both Product and Print and removing at all, still not working  as expected

Comment: you only need to `persist` new entities (when you would insert), I'm not 100% on this, but I think you need to persist only the new Print entities, and also you have a double `,` after your cascade annotation - maybe that is all

Comment: double `,` it's only typo here, as I'm not show a real code, it's simplified version and I made a type, I'll fix a typo. About persisting only `Print`, it make no sense, my main entity is `Product` and that is why we have this cascade/orphan options, to have ability to persist all nested entities with a main entity. In real code my `Product` has dependencies to more than 5 child objects and I do not want to persist each of them separately.

Answer (score 0):

You have to persist the New Print entity:

```
$product = $em->find(Product::class, $id);
$product->udpate($name, $description, $available);
$print = new Print($product, $key, $value);
$product->replacePrint($print);

$em->persist($print);

$em->persist($product);
$em->flush();
```

Comment: umm, 2 questions: 1. why I do not need it for creating (as I told on product creation it also creating print without explicitly persisting it) 2) what `cascade={"persist"}` is for then (https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.8/reference/working-with-associations.html#transitive-persistence-cascade-operations)???